# Insert Chinese character into MySQL through node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, character-encoding, encode, big5

I am now connecting to an old MySQL db (version: 4.0.18-nt) with Node.js with mysql driver. The database default collation is latin1.

mysql character setting:

```
character set   latin1  latin1
character sets  latin1 big5 czech euc_kr gb2312 gbk latin1_de sjis tis620 ujis dec8 dos german1 hp8 koi8_ru latin2 swe7 usa7 cp1251 danish hebrew win1251 estonia hungarian koi8_ukr win1251ukr greek win1250 croat cp1257 latin5   latin1 big5 czech euc_kr gb2312 gbk latin1_de sjis tis620 ujis dec8 dos german1 hp8 koi8_ru latin2 swe7 usa7 cp1251 danish hebrew win1251 estonia hungarian koi8_ukr win1251ukr greek win1250 croat cp1257 latin5
```

When I insert Chinese Character into the db, it will become garbled code.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'pwd',
    database: 'user',
    charset: 'BIG5' // I have tried 'utf8'/'latin1'/'BIG5' 
});

connection.query(`update user set chi_surname = '陳', chi_other_name = '陳大文' where user_id = '1'`
    , async function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log('The solution is: ', results);
        console.log(fields)
    });
```

Result in mysql

```
chi_surname   chi_other_name
�䒰          �䒰憭扳��

I tried to convert above text (�䒰�䒰憭扳��) to utf-8, then it show 陳大文.
```

If I update the field in phyMyAdmin directly, it can update properly.

```
chi_surname   chi_other_name
陳            大文
```

It seems that the mysql driver will send the query to Mysql in utf-8 no matter what charset I put in the connection config.

I know that changing the default collation of the db to utf-8 can solve the problem, but as there are many old program calling the database as well, so changing db collation can't be an option.

I also tried by using the third party libraries (iconv-lite, encoding) to change the word to BIG5/latin1 before inserting, but still fail.

Is there any method I could insert Chinese character into this db? Thank you.

```
Node version:node v15.6.0
node-mysql version: 2.18.1
```

(from comment)

```
CREATE TABLE department (
    'dept_id' varchar(10) NOT NULL default '', 
    'dept_code' varchar(10) default NULL, 
    'chi_name' varchar(50) default NULL, 
    'eng_name' varchar(50) NOT NULL default ''
) TYPE=MyISAM
```

Comment: 4.0.18 is not just "old", it is "antique"!  Would you do `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...` so I can diagnose the problem further.  Note: 4.0 had no concept of character sets. Having phpmysqladmin set to latin1 is possibly the right kludge.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still dealing with this "antique"!
If you are still interested in this antique, one of the result of `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM` is  牛池灣 A4FBA6C0C657 

For anyone who comes late, I finally figured out the root problem is node-mysql only support UTF-8 / ASCII encoding, so even I encode my sql query in big5 before passing to the driver, it comes up with garbled code.

I have added the iconv-lite for the encoding part in node-mysql so it can support big-5 encoding and now finally can insert Chinese property. 
here's the folk: [link](https://github.com/ckc2715/mysql)

Answer (score 0):

`A4FBA6C0C657` is the Big5 encoding for `牛池灣`.  So you need `CHARACTER SET big5`.

The connection, the column definition, etc.

Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

You seem to have this already:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({ ... , charset : 'big5'});
```

So the probably is probably elsewhere.

It is OK to have the column in a different charset than the connection; the conversion should be handled correctly.

Please check the MySQL version with

```
SELECT @@version;
```

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`
Result: 
`character_set latin1
character_sets latin1 big5 czech euc_kr gb2312 gbk latin1_de sjis...`

`SHOW CREATE TABLE department;`
Result:
`CREATE TABLE department ('dept_id' varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
 'dept_code' varchar(10) default NULL,
 'chi_name' varchar(50) default NULL,
 'eng_name' varchar(50) NOT NULL default ''
) TYPE=MyISAM
`

`SELECT @@version;`

Result:
`4.0.18-nt`

Thank you @RickJames

Comment: 4.0.18, which is about 2 decades old!  That version did not have any concept of `CHARACTER SET`.  So, my comments about Big5 are mostly irrelevant.  Where is "character sets  latin1 big5 czech ..." coming from?  Try changing the connection parameter to be latin1 instead of big5.  Yes, that is "wrong", but it might be a valid workaround.